# Cumulocity existing plugins sources available?

Tags: cumulocity

Are the sources for the pre-defined plugins available for further use? I couldn't find anything in the bitbucket repo where the ui-examples are.

I'd like to implement a more complex plugin than the examples provide based on the Device Management "Software"-Tab of the device details view.

Therefore the sources would help!

Comment: For anyone not knowing which repo I meant: https://bitbucket.org/m2m/

Comment: Atm they are not available but there are plans to open source it.